# \vspace is swallowing my column

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I am using

```
\vspace*{1cm}
```

in my table..
Unfortunately, the column seems to have dissapeared at the location where I am placing my /vscpace..

See the picture [image]

```
   \multirow{3}{*}{Rayleigh }  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\mathop{\sigma
}\nolimits^{2} =\sqrt{\frac{1}{2n} \sum
_{i=1}^{n}\mathop{v}\nolimits_{i}^{2}  }$}
\\\vspace{0.5cm}
                           &      $\gamma $: continuous location parameter                                         \\\vspace{0.5cm}
                           & $\sigma$: is the continuous scale
                           parameter\\\hline
```

Comment: Hi and welcome, can you add the code that produces the output you have have shown? Best in form of a compilable example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\\[0.5cm]` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
       \multirow{3}[12]{*}{Rayleigh }  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\mathop{\sigma
}\nolimits^{2} =√{\frac{1}{2n} \sum
_{i=1}ⁿ\mathop{v}\nolimits_{i}^{2}  }$}
\\[0.5cm]
                           &      $γ$: continuous location parameter                                         \\[0.5cm]
                           & $\sigma$: is the continuous scale
                           parameter\\\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For your table, the best option is probably to just expand the entire thing, using `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{<stretch factor>}`. This will expand the whole table, while keeping all the lines intact. You can use `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}` after this table if you don't want it to effect any other tables in your document.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
    \hline
       \multirow{3}{*}{Rayleigh }  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\mathop{\sigma
    }\nolimits^{2} =\sqrt{\frac{1}{2n} \sum
    _{i=1}^{n}\mathop{v}\nolimits_{i}^{2}  }$}
    \\
                               & $\gamma $: continuous location parameter\\\
                               & $\sigma$: is the continuous scale parameter\\\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: i already used rows, my issue here is i want a bigger space between my equations.

Comment: @Ellie Could you post the code for that table? It'll help to see what the problem is and what possible solutions might be.

Comment: see the question, i added the table part @Ryan

Comment: But you omitted `\begin{table}{columns?}` so it's hard to know what exactly the problem is. Best practice here is to isolate the problem to a MWE, a short standalone document.

Comment: @Ellie I edited my comment to give you an answer that works with the table you provided.

Comment: thanks a lot @Ryan and Harish Kumar, both your answers worked perfectly..